# Python: Write encrypted data to file

Tags: python, file, encryption, encode

I've made a chat app for school, and some people just write into the database. So my new project on it is to encrypt the resources. So I've made an encrypt function.

It's working fine, but when I try to write a encrypted data at a file, I get an error Message:

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x94' in position 0:         
character maps to <undefined>
```

How to fix that problem?

complete code:

```
def encrypts(data, step):
    newdata = ""
    i = 0
    while (len(data) > len(step)):
        step += step[i]
        i += 1
    if (len(data) < len(step)):
        step = step[:len(data)]
    for i in range(len(data)):
        a = ord(data[i])
        b = ord(step[i])
        newdata += chr(a+b)
    return newdata

file = open("C:/Users/David/Desktop/file.msg","wb")
file.write(encrypts("12345","code"))
```

Now, I finally solved my problem. The created ASCII Characters didn't exist. So I changed my functions:

```
def encrypts(data, step):
    newdata = ""
    i = 0
    while (len(data) > len(step)):
        step += step[i]
        i += 1
    if (len(data) < len(step)):
        step = step[:len(data)]
    for i in range(len(data)):
        a = ord(data[i])
        b = ord(step[i])
        newdata += chr(a+b-100)     #The "-100" fixed the problem.
    return newdata
```

Comment: You should post your answer as a separate answer and don't include in in your *question*. Also you can mark your issue as solved when you *accept* it.

Comment: I believe that solution will still crash if users type in certain characters, wouldn't it? I've actually had this same exact issue in the past while creating the same exact software, funny enough. I fixed it with base64 encoding. I also support keys so that if 2 people use the same password, its impossible to decrypt, even if you run the server! You can run IMGUI.py and connect to the chatroom by typing /connect in the bottom gray box my source code is here (let me know if you want to see the serverside part too): http://digitaldiscrepancy.com/IMSafe.zip

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in the encoding of the file.

Try it:

> `inputFile = codecs.open('input.txt', 'rb', 'cp1251')
>   outFile = codecs.open('output.txt', 'wb', 'cp1251')`

Answer (score 0):

When opening a file for writing or saving, try adding the 'b' character to the open mode. So instead of :

```
open("encryptedFile.txt", 'w')
```

use

```
open("encryptedFile.txt", 'wb')
```

This will open files as binary, which is necessary when you modify the characters the way you are because you're sometime setting those characters to values outside of the ASCII range.

Comment: Thanks guess that's a great idea. How to convert str to binary?

Comment: You don't have to do anything special. Just write the string like you normally would and python does the rest.

Comment: Um No... : "TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface"

Comment: If I'm not mistaken Python requires [explicit encoding](http://www.pythoncentral.io/encoding-and-decoding-strings-in-python-3-x/) in v3.